# IMAP Fetch Encoding

Tags: python, character-encoding, imap, imaplib, gmail-imap

I'm trying to fetch some email info from gmail using imap like this

```
"(BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (subject from date)] X-GM-MSGID X-GM-LABELS X-GM-THRID)"
```

The problem is that it doesn't work well with special and accented characters. For example,

```
Stéphane Maniaci
```

is rendered as

```
=?ISO-8859-1?Q?St=E9phane_Maniaci?=
```

How do I tell Gmail to return the strings with an encoding of my choice, say I want Charset to be UTF-8.

How to adjust that in the IMAP command I mentioned above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay. I found out that email.utils can help out a lot here.

It has methods to parse date, emails, and any other information from imap messages.

It also has methods to decode imap strings. Like this

```
from email.header import decode_header
value, charset = decode_header(string_to_be_decoded)
```