# python email encoding and decoding problems

Tags: python, email, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

Basically I want to read all new emails from an inbox and put them in a database. The reason I use python is because it has `imaplib`, but I know nothing about it.

Currently, I have something like this :

```
def primitive_get_text_blocks(email_message_instance):
    maintype = email_message_instance.get_content_maintype()
    if maintype == 'multipart':
        return_parts = ""
        for part in email_message_instance.get_payload():
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'text':
                return_parts+= " "+ part.get_payload()
        return return_parts
    elif maintype == 'text':
        return email_message_instance.get_payload()
    return ""

fromField=con.escape(email_message["From"])
contentField=con.escape(primitive_get_text_blocks(email_message))
```

primitive `get_text_blocks` is copy pasted from somewhere.
The result is that I get database entries like this :

```
<META http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3DUTF-8">
```

From what I understand, that has something to do with being encoded in `utf-7`. So I changed to `get_payload(decode=True)`, but that gives me byte-arrays. If I append another `decode('utf-8')`, it sometimes crashes with errors like

> 'codec error can't decode to ...'.

I don't know how encodings work, I only want a unicode string with the body of my email.

Why is there no simple `convert(charset from, charset to)`? How do I get a readable email body (and address?). I've discovered [IMAP Fetch Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969639/imap-fetch-encoding) and using `decode_header` I got no further.

--

I assume encoding is the way bytes represent characters, so with that in mind, shouldn't decode take a byte array and spit out a string? and here on stack overflow I came across somebody claming it had something to do with beeing encoded with `utf-8` and `utf-7`. What does that even mean?

I did google and there appear to be tons of duplicates but the answers they got didn't really help me out (I've tried most of them)

Comment: That's not UTF-7, that's quoted-printable. Generally you should expect most single-part body parts to be either QP or base64-encoded. The `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header tells you which (or no encoding, which is one of `7bit`, `8bit`, or `binary`).

Comment: For text parts, you should not assume UTF-8 or try to guess; you should be examining the `charset` attribute of the `Content-Type` header.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's quite easy. Even though all documentation points to the glorious past when the unicode function still was a real thing, 'str' does the same.

So to recap, you have to pass 'decode=True' with 'getPayload' and wrap that around a str(...,'utf-8').